# How to index and query array field by multiple AND conditions ($all operator)

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a large collection of documents (currently around 100 mil, going up few mil monthly), each having `rule:[]` field which is populated by "random" positive integers (representing matched rules by another app module). Field usually has somewhere between 10 and 30 integers, but will probably grow in time. Multikey index was added on that field (index itself is around 6gb.

I'm currently testing locally - mongo up in docker with 8gb ram and 2vcpu available, but have test cluster available (3 node, each 4vcpu & 10gb) to try out ideas

When I write a simple query looking for documents having 1 integer matched in said array, it returns in under 20 ms, eg:

```
db.mycoll.find({ rule: 55 })
db.mycoll.find({ rule: { $elemMatch: { $eq: 55 } } })
// Also, OR seems to be non-issue as well (following query works really fast too):
db.mycoll.find({ rule: { $in: [55, 66, 77] } })
```

But I need to query all documents having 2 or 3 integers matched, and such a query never goes below 7-10 sec. I tried many combinations, but it seems winning query plan always boils down to:

```
db.mycoll.find({ rule: { $all: [55, 66, 77] } })
```

From what I've read thus far - it might not be possible to optimize such a query? Can anything be done?

Should I increase resources to try to fit index into ram? If so, how can I control its *pinned*?

I'm even open to alternatives (prefer to stay fully on mongo now though):

- use different collection to insert combination of `{_id, rule}`
- use relational database?
- use some other technology - eg. have mongo store data, redis or something else provide fast lookups? (maybe raising mongo memory limit would offer similar effect?)
- Store data in some other way which would be easier to search (assume its sorted, int array), eg:

  - Instead of an array store string such as `1-2-55-66-77-2929` and then search for `55-66-77` string instead?
  - Play with bitmasks? eg: array of objects, each having 32 or 64 bits for rule ids.. Kinda hard to maintain and reliably build queries.
  - any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use aggregation framework to do a $project stage, and use $setIntersection to add a new field like this:

```
{
  $project: {
    remains: {
      $setIntersection: [[55, 66, 77], "$rule"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then using $match stage to filter out the results that remains size smaller than 2.

Comment: If you can build an compound index with this "rule" field multikey index, then buy using the compound to do the query, it will narrow down the results to a small set and save you a lot of time, because although you have a multikey index built on the "rule" field, but it still will do a collection scan first.

Comment: Unfortunately result remains the same (worse even). `$setIntersection` is really fast, but subsequent `$match` is causing issues.

Comment: Compound index is not an option since query has no other parameter than `rule` :(